# Is there a way to capture powershell script executed output without using System.Management.Automation

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, amazon-web-services

The below method launches a powershell script and executes it

```
 private static void LaunchPowershell()
    {
        string exeDir = "H:\\aws-newAPIKey";

        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe";
        startInfo.Arguments = exeDir + "\\newApiKey_wh1.ps1";
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = exeDir;

        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
```

This results in the following output in the command line:

```
CreatedDate     : 1/3/2018 7:20:16 PM
CustomerId      : 
Description     : This is api key for customer
Enabled         : True
Id              : qraj84yl5h
LastUpdatedDate : 1/3/2018 7:20:16 PM
Name            : newAPIKey7
StageKeys       : {}
Value           : 2LBtWluNX1XbgtDG0SPY1IQgnVDkZTwzmgY3kd60
```

What I want to do is to obtain the Value of the API key created in C#. Is there a way to do this without using System.Management.Autmomation library?

Comment: instead of using `Process.Start` why not you use `PowerShell` class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retrieve complex data from powershell by executing a process, then you could use [ConvertTo-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-5.1) on the powershell object, and [parse it in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c)

Although it looks like you're trying to create an API key for AWS, so why not just use the [AWS SDK for .NET](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/)?

Comment: The proper way to do it is by using AWS SDK

           process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.Start();
            while (!process.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
            {
                string line = process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                // do something with line
            }
Parse it to get whichever value you require..

This is the solution that I used without using the powershell class

Answer (score 2):

Your PowerShell pipeline runs the **newApiKey_wh1.ps1** script which presumably returns the output you have shown.

Without knowing more about the script I'll have to guess, but you should be able to use the `Select-Object` statement on the output that is returned by the script to just the value you want.

So, if the script does something like:

```
return $Key
```

Then you could try:

```
return ($Key | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value)
```

This will pull out just the value of the property named **Value**.